# How to replace cloudy pixels in Gaussian Distribution Plot?

Tags: python, machine-learning, geospatial, exploratory-data-analysis

I have given dataset called train_df which consists of 34 numerical features (NDVI_1 to NDVI_34) and a categorical class label (crop).

[1][Concise summary of train_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhpum.png)

[2][PDF of some NDVIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rr17.png)

I want to replace the dips in the PDFs of each row i.e., I want to replace all the missing values and values <=50 with nearby values row-wise. I have tried KNN imputer but my results aren't improving. Which technique should I use?

For Training Dataset

```
# Replace values <= 50 with NULL
train_df.loc[:, 'NDVI_1':'NDVI_34'] = train_df.loc[:, 'NDVI_1':'NDVI_34'].where(train_df.loc[:, 'NDVI_1':'NDVI_34'] > 50, np.nan)

# Apply KNN imputation row-wise
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)  # Adjust n_neighbors as desired
train_df.loc[:, 'NDVI_1':'NDVI_34'] = imputer.fit_transform(train_df.loc[:, 'NDVI_1':'NDVI_34'])

# Round imputed values to integers if needed
train_df.loc[:, 'NDVI_1':'NDVI_34'] = train_df.loc[:, 'NDVI_1':'NDVI_34'].round().astype(int)
```

Comment: The imputation is column-wise. If you want row-wise, you could transpose your features and then run KNNImputer and the transpose back.